# Creating a xls file using javascript, downloading an unsupported format

Tags: javascript, html, excel, ms-office, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to create a **.xls file** using JavaScript. When I try to open the file it shows a warning, also when I try to edit and save it. It wants me to create a new file out of it or else it stores all of its necessary data in a separate folder, or else I have to convert it to compatible mode.

```
        var tableBody  = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1252">';
        tableBody +='<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name> Quotation </x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes><y:Panes></y:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions>';
        tableBody +='</x:ExcelWorksheet>';
        tableBody +='</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>';
        tableBody +=quoteBody.substringBetween('<html>','</html>' );
        tableBody +='</body></html>';



        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.download = quoteFileName+'.xls';
        downloadLink.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'+response.getReturnValue();
        downloadLink.click();
```

[When I try to open the downloaded excel file. I click yes to open it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2gTo.png)

[When I try to save the downloaded excel file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK8RA.png)

What am I going wrong? Is it with the excel version or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say here: **It wants me to create a new file out of it or else it stores all of its necessary data in a separate folder, or else I have to convert it to compatible mode.** please explain.

Comment: When i try to edit and save the excel file. the file prompts to create a new file with the same contents or else it will create a separate folder in the file location to store all the contents (images and sheet data) of the file. in order to use the file later.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually creating Excel file, you are more or less "faking" it (using special app-specific markup). I would recommend you use normal library to create normal Excel file, like [sheet.js](https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs). Then these problems will be gone.